# Object transformation to another structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I want to transform an object into another structure. Here is the original object:

```js
[{
  "id": "2IJXhq",
  "fields": [{
    "key": "FirstName",
    "value": "David"
  }, {
    "key": "LastName",
    "value": "Smith"
  }, {
    "key": "Age",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "key": "Profession",
    "value": "engineer"
  }, {
    "key": "DOB",
    "value": "1990-03-11"
  }, {
    "key": "Gender",
    "value": "male"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "5BTGyk",
  "fields": [{
    "key": "FirstName",
    "value": "Robert"
  }, {
    "key": "LastName",
    "value": "Conner"
  }, {
    "key": "Age",
    "value": 40
  }, {
    "key": "Profession",
    "value": "doctor"
  }, {
    "key": "DOB",
    "value": "1960-04-22"
  }, {
    "key": "Gender",
    "value": "male"
  }]
}]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```js
[{
  "id": "2IJXhq",
  "person": [{
    "FirstName": "David",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Profession": "engineer",
    "Age": 30,
    "DOB": "1990-03-11",
    "Gender": "male"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "5BTGyk",
  "person": [{
    "FirstName": "Robert",
    "LastName": "Conner",
    "Profession": "doctor",
    "Age": 40,
    "DOB": "1990-03-11",
    "Gender": "male"
  }]
}]
```

Some thoughts were trying to use Map, reduce as below

```
let arr = [{"id":"2IJXhq","person":[{"FirstName":"David","LastName":"Smith","Profession":"engineer","Age":30,"DOB":"1990-03-11","Gender":"male"}]},{"id":"5BTGyk","person":[{"FirstName":"Robert","LastName":"Conner","Profession":"doctor","Age":40,"DOB":"1990-03-11","Gender":"male"}]}]
let o = arr.map(item => item.reduce((a, {key, Value}) => ({[key]: Value, ...a} ), {}))

console.log(o)
```

But that does not seem to work.

The above object is being used in the below simple HTML page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Concise Handlebars.js</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="anchor">People
 </div>
 <script id="tpl" type="text/template">
  {{#each this}}
  <div>
   <a href="{{id}}">{{id}} </a>
   {{#each fields}}
   <p>
    {{key}} : {{value}}
   </p>
   {{/each}}
  </div>
  {{/each}}
 </script>
 <script>
  var slingshot = function (url, tplId, anchor) {
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           console.log(data);
              var template = $(tplId).html();
              var stone = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
              $(anchor).append(stone);
     });
  }
    slingshot('//api.jsonbin.io/b/5b7eca766376d24455aa55f8', '#tpl', '#anchor');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that nothing about what you have has anything to do with JSON; it's an object. I've amended the question as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each `fields` property of the objects in your array and use `reduce()` to generate a new object based on the original array of objects. Try this:

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.fields = item.fields.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.key] = item.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
```

```js
let arr = [{
  "id": "2IJXhq",
  "fields": [{
    "key": "FirstName",
    "value": "David"
  }, {
    "key": "LastName",
    "value": "Smith"
  }, {
    "key": "Age",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "key": "Profession",
    "value": "engineer"
  }, {
    "key": "DOB",
    "value": "1990-03-11"
  }, {
    "key": "Gender",
    "value": "male"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "5BTGyk",
  "fields": [{
    "key": "FirstName",
    "value": "Robert"
  }, {
    "key": "LastName",
    "value": "Conner"
  }, {
    "key": "Age",
    "value": 40
  }, {
    "key": "Profession",
    "value": "doctor"
  }, {
    "key": "DOB",
    "value": "1960-04-22"
  }, {
    "key": "Gender",
    "value": "male"
  }]
}]

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.fields = item.fields.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.key] = item.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added comments to the javascript detailing each step it is doing.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "2IJXhq",
    "fields": [{
        "key": "FirstName",
        "value": "David"
      },
      {
        "key": "LastName",
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "key": "Profession",
        "value": "engineer"
      },
      {
        "key": "DOB",
        "value": "1990-03-11"
      },
      {
        "key": "Gender",
        "value": "male"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "5BTGyk",
    "fields": [{
        "key": "FirstName",
        "value": "Robert"
      },
      {
        "key": "LastName",
        "value": "Conner"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 40
      },
      {
        "key": "Profession",
        "value": "doctor"
      },
      {
        "key": "DOB",
        "value": "1960-04-22"
      },
      {
        "key": "Gender",
        "value": "male"
      }
    ]
  }
];

//loop over each data element
data.forEach(function(person){
  //create a new person property from all the fields
  person.person = person.fields.reduce(function(person, fieldObject){
    //put the key value pair on the new person object
    person[fieldObject.key] = fieldObject.value;
    return person;
  }, {});
  
  //remove the old fields property
  delete person.fields;
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to generate the desired output:

```js
const data=[{id:"2IJXhq",fields:[{key:"FirstName",value:"David"},{key:"LastName",value:"Smith"},{key:"Age",value:30},{key:"Profession",value:"engineer"},{key:"DOB",value:"1990-03-11"},{key:"Gender",value:"male"}]},{id:"5BTGyk",fields:[{key:"FirstName",value:"Robert"},{key:"LastName",value:"Conner"},{key:"Age",value:40},{key:"Profession",value:"doctor"},{key:"DOB",value:"1960-04-22"},{key:"Gender",value:"male"}]}];

const result = data.map(({id, fields}) => ({id, person: fields.reduce((all,{key, value}) => (all[key] = value,  all), {})}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with your existing [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": "2IJXhq",
    "fields": [{
        "key": "FirstName",
        "value": "David"
      },
      {
        "key": "LastName",
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "key": "Profession",
        "value": "engineer"
      },
      {
        "key": "DOB",
        "value": "1990-03-11"
      },
      {
        "key": "Gender",
        "value": "male"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "5BTGyk",
    "fields": [{
        "key": "FirstName",
        "value": "Robert"
      },
      {
        "key": "LastName",
        "value": "Conner"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 40
      },
      {
        "key": "Profession",
        "value": "doctor"
      },
      {
        "key": "DOB",
        "value": "1960-04-22"
      },
      {
        "key": "Gender",
        "value": "male"
      }
    ]
  }
]



let expected = [];
arr.map(function(item, index) {
  expected[index] = {
    'id': item.id
  };
  item.fields = item.fields.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.key] = item.value;
    expected[index]['person'] = obj;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

console.log(expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{"id":"2IJXhq","fields":[{"key":"FirstName","value":"David"},{"key":"LastName","value":"Smith"},{"key":"Age","value":30},{"key":"Profession","value":"engineer"},{"key":"DOB","value":"1990-03-11"},{"key":"Gender","value":"male"}]},{"id":"5BTGyk","fields":[{"key":"FirstName","value":"Robert"},{"key":"LastName","value":"Conner"},{"key":"Age","value":40},{"key":"Profession","value":"doctor"},{"key":"DOB","value":"1960-04-22"},{"key":"Gender","value":"male"}]}];

var newMap = arr.map(({ id, fields }) => {
  const person = fields.reduce((person, { key, value }) => ({...person, [key]: value }));
  return { id, person };
});

console.log(newMap);
```

You might use `Object.assign({ person, [key]: value })` for better performance.